# How to use vtkDataSetAttributes to hide some cells from rendering in a structured grid?

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a field of sparse matrices that represent a voxelization. If the value in the sparse matrix is > 0 (present in sparse matrix), then that voxel is active. Otherwise, it is inactive.

I am trying to render this using VTK's structured grids.

So, I need a way to hide the inactive voxels so they do not render/are invisible. The VTK documentation mentions: *to 'turn-off' points and cells in the dataset, set vtkDataSetAttributes::HIDDENCELL in the ghost array for each point / cell that needs to be blanked.*

However, I cannot figure out how to do so.

My assumption would be to create an array of ghost types for the cells, similar to how the scalars are set. However, this does not work, as there is no "CellGhostTypesArray" similar to how there are "vtkDoubleArray".

The code in question is as follows, and is mostly copied from VTK's [structured grid example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/StructuredGrid/StructuredGrid/).

```
bool Vtk3DViewer::renderSnapshotActorStructured(int snapshotID, VoxelData* voxelData)
{
    const Snapshot& snapshot = *(voxelData->getSnapshot(snapshotID));
    int voxelCount = (snapshot.voxelCount)->data();

    if (!voxelCount)
    {
        return false;
    }

    size_t numVoxelsX = snapshot.value->data().n_rows;
    size_t numVoxelsY = snapshot.value->data()[0].n_rows;
    size_t numVoxelsZ = snapshot.value->data()[0].n_cols;

    size_t numVerticesX = snapshot.value->data().n_rows + 1;
    size_t numVerticesY = snapshot.value->data()[0].n_rows + 1;
    size_t numVerticesZ = snapshot.value->data()[0].n_cols + 1;

    auto dataSize = numVerticesX * numVerticesY * numVerticesZ;

    // Note, what VTK calls "cells" will be our Voxels
    auto numberOfCells = numVoxelsX * numVoxelsY * numVoxelsZ;

    // The vertices
    vtkNew<vtkPoints> points;

    AABBLite* bounds = voxelData->voxelizationBounds;
    abstract::Array<float, 3>* minimumPoint = bounds->minimumPoint;
    float voxelWidth = voxelData->voxelWidth->data();
    double halfVoxel = voxelWidth / 2.0;

    int iVoxel = 0;
    vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> cellValues;
    cellValues->SetNumberOfTuples(numberOfCells);

    vtkNew<vtkDataSetAttributes::CellGhostTypes> ghostTypes;
    //ghostTypes->SetNumberOfTuples(numberOfCells);

    for (int zVert = 0; zVert < numVerticesZ; zVert++)
    {
        float z = minimumPoint->at(2) + (voxelWidth * zVert);

        for (int yVert = 0; yVert < numVerticesY; yVert++)
        {
            float y = minimumPoint->at(1) + (voxelWidth * yVert);

            for (int xVert = 0; xVert < numVerticesX; xVert++)
            {
                float x = minimumPoint->at(0) + (voxelWidth * xVert);
                points->InsertNextPoint(x, y, z);

                const arma::SpMat<float>& valuesSlice = snapshot.value->data()[xVert];

                if (xVert < numVoxelsX && yVert < numVoxelsY && zVert < numVoxelsZ)
                {
                    float value = valuesSlice.at(yVert, zVert);
                    cellValues->SetValue(iVoxel, value);

                    iVoxel++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a grid
    vtkNew<vtkStructuredGrid> structuredGrid;

    // Specify the dimensions of the grid
    structuredGrid->SetDimensions(
      static_cast<int>(numVerticesX), static_cast<int>(numVerticesY), static_cast<int>(numVerticesZ));
    structuredGrid->SetPoints(points);
    structuredGrid->GetCellData()->SetScalars(cellValues);

    // The key is the cell Id and the value is a set of corresponding point Ids.
    std::map<vtkIdType, std::set<vtkIdType>> cellPointIds;
    vtkCellIterator* it = structuredGrid->NewCellIterator();
    for (it->InitTraversal(); !it->IsDoneWithTraversal(); it->GoToNextCell())
    {
        vtkIdList* pointIds = it->GetPointIds();
        std::set<vtkIdType> ptIds;
        for (vtkIdType* id = pointIds->begin(); id != pointIds->end(); ++id)
        {
            ptIds.insert(*id);
        }
        cellPointIds[it->GetCellId()] = ptIds;
    }
    it->Delete();

    // Create a mapper and actor
    vtkNew<vtkDataSetMapper> mapper;
    mapper->SetInputData(structuredGrid);
    mapper->UseLookupTableScalarRangeOn();
    mapper->SetLookupTable(getLookupTable());
    mapper->SetColorModeToMapScalars();
    mapper->InterpolateScalarsBeforeMappingOn();

    vtkNew<vtkActor> actor;
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    addActorToScene(snapshotID, snapshot.timestamp->data(), actor);

    return true;
}
```

There's also something like `vtkNew<vtkCellData>`, which does have "attributes". However, none of these seem to line up with ghost types:

```
  // Always keep NUM_ATTRIBUTES as the last entry
  enum AttributeTypes
  {
    SCALARS = 0,
    VECTORS = 1,
    NORMALS = 2,
    TCOORDS = 3,
    TENSORS = 4,
    GLOBALIDS = 5,
    PEDIGREEIDS = 6,
    EDGEFLAG = 7,
    TANGENTS = 8,
    RATIONALWEIGHTS = 9,
    HIGHERORDERDEGREES = 10,
    NUM_ATTRIBUTES
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vtructuredGrid has a BlankCell() call which seems hide cells from rendering.

Just call structuredGrid->BlankCell(iCell) on any cells (voxels) desired to be hidden. Just note that you need to set the dimensions of the structured grid first.